# my model is much bigger than the 3d and 0-1 space

Tags: uv, 3d-view, units

[image]I am new to blender and 3d. i have a model i'd like to UV map with a custom design. However the model is huge compared to the 3d space and 0-1 space. what do I do or where do I go to get an answer? I asked Lynda.com and the response was they didn't know and couldn't help me, any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Although I can't answer your question, I suggest that you add pictures, and maybe even a link to download your .blend file. This way it'll be easier to understand your problem

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 0-1 space, if you imported the model you could scale it down. In object mode select the object, press 'S' and enter 0.01 this would scale it to 1% of its previous size.

Comment: here's an image. i intend to print this once i have mapped it - i really appreciate the help and apologies for taking so long to reply. i've been really ill

Comment: it needs to fit the phone perfectly; artwork needs to be very high quality so i don't think scaling is an option(?)

Answer (score 2):

Remember, size in the computer is a relative, mathematical construct (it's not real) Size becomes an issue when you are stressing the the limits of the math engine. examples: If you build a model of a cup and you have the scale very large, relative to the programs space you'll have a crazy time detailing it, likewise an intricate model of a ship built "very small" will give you fits. You are translating the mathematical construct in the computer to a reasonable size for mapping pixel information to parts.

You should try to work in those "units" that make sense for the object: cup in inches, ship in meters. It's all about your modelling space. Then use reasonable UV mapping for the object. (don't try to use a single UV map for an entire ship model) So it's all about the scaling, bounds, mapping....

Then this link might get you going?
https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/uv_image/texturing/unwrapping.html

Hope this helps.
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

I think we need more information for help you , like some screen or file.

If I found an excessive big model the first thing to try is select all pressing A on object mode looking if everything get a diferent color border, meaning it's selected. 
Later, scale down using S key and sliding your mouse expecting some changes. You can also can try to press the "." on numeric keyboard: That centers the view to see your entire model, and then scale it with the scale method.